# rake assets:precompile stuck

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

couple of days ago i noticed that jquery calendar is not working on my deployment site(heroku). on digging out the problem i noticed that source of site on my dev server has some 100 script tags related to bootstrap(i am using twitter bootstrap css) but on prod server. i have 4 script tags. on searching i found that i should run `rake assets:precompile` on my rails console fo asset pipeline. but while running it is taking terribly long time, last time it took 6 hours and i had to abort it.

referring to many sites and post, i found that i should change `config.serve_static_assets`to `true` and `config.assets.compile` to `true`. but problem is still there. i also tried to remove `jquery-rails/jquery-ui-rails` from `gem`but problem is still there.
here is my `config/environmnets/production.rb`

```
ProductRecall::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true



  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
   config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5

  config.action_controller.perform_caching  = false
end
```

my `config/application.rb` looks like this

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module ProductRecall
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable escaping HTML in JSON.
    config.active_support.escape_html_entities_in_json = true

    # Enforce whitelist mode for mass assignment.
    # This will create an empty whitelist of attributes available for mass-assignment for all models
    # in your app. As such, your models will need to explicitly whitelist or blacklist accessible
    # parameters by using an attr_accessible or attr_protected declaration.
    config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
    config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
  end
end
```

here is my Gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby, :platforms => :ruby
gem 'faker', '1.0.1'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.6'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem "google_visualr", "~> 2.1.0" 
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", :require => "simple_captcha"
gem 'rufus-scheduler'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '2.5.0'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
end

#gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

plz let me know what is wrong here. as i am terribly stuck with no clue since 2 days

Comment: The best way to fix a problem like this is to remove functionality until you get it working. I surmise it's probably a Gem issue, but you can only tell by testing

Comment: means i should remove gems that i am not using in my app??

Comment: I meant you should temporarily disable everything you can until you find what's causing the error, then work to resolve that specific issue :)

Comment: When you deploy to heroku does it output any errors or messages when it attempts to precompile the assets as part of the deploy? Does '/public/assets/manifest.yml' exist in your repo? If so, heroku will assume assets have already been compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also faced the same problem. Actually gem gets conflict. Here 'rufus-scheduler' gem is the culprit. Try to remove the gem and deploy.

Next you can try this

```
task :precompile, :roles => :web, :except => { :no_release => true } do 
  run_locally("rm -rf public/assets/*") 
  run_locally("bundle exec rake assets:precompile") 
  servers = find_servers_for_task(current_task) 
  port_option = port ? " -e 'ssh -p #{port}' " : '' 
  servers.each do |server| 
    run_locally("rsync --recursive --times --rsh=ssh --compress -- 
    human-readable #{port_option} --progress public/assets #{user} @#{server}:         {shared_path}") 
  end 
end
```